# Did you rename table_name.pid to table.id (a BigAutoField)? [y/N]

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

I have been running a Django app for last couple of weeks with no issues. However I started to see the above warning message out of no where when I tried to make migration (renaming `invoice_date` to `order_date`).

When I closely look at the migration files, I see that the initial migration file auto created the `pid` column. But when I describe the tables in dev (sqlite3) the column name is in fact `id`.

Just to confirm I did not attempt to rename the column name from `pid` to `id`. So I can't get my head around as to what is going on. If Django auto creates a column, it should manage the columns forever. Any intentional or unintentional changes to auto created columns should be blocked by Django.

Below are the module verion I am using.

```
Django==3.2.2 
whitenoise==5.0 
pandas==0.25.3
```

Detailed migration log:

```
(venv) [prj(master)]$python manage.py makemigrations
Did you rename packaging.pid to packaging.id (a BigAutoField)? [y/N] n
Did you rename product.pid to product.id (a BigAutoField)? [y/N] n
Did you rename purchase.pid to purchase.id (a BigAutoField)? [y/N] n
Did you rename sale.pid to sale.id (a BigAutoField)? [y/N] n
Did you rename saleschannel.pid to saleschannel.id (a BigAutoField)? [y/N] n
Did you rename supplier.pid to supplier.id (a BigAutoField)? [y/N] n
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'id' to packaging without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
Select an option: 2
(venv) [prj(master)]
```

Initial migration file:

```
   operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Product',
            fields=[
                ('pid', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('mpn', models.CharField(max_length=6)),
                ('name', models.CharField(max_length=100)),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Purchase',
            fields=[
                ('pid', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('invoice_date', models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today, verbose_name='Invoice Date')),
                ('invoice_number', models.CharField(max_length=100)),
                ('supplier', models.CharField(max_length=50)),
                ('description', models.CharField(max_length=200)),
                ('amount_ex_vat', models.FloatField()),
                ('vat', models.FloatField()),
                ('total', models.FloatField()),
            ],
        ),
```

Comment: This might sound dumb but did you perhaps run a find and replace in your project where you replaced id with pid? Django automatically generates primary key fields with the name `id` not `pid`. This or perhaps previously you ran a modified version of Django which generated fields named `pid` instead of `id` is what I can think happened. As below comment states just edit your migration files and correct them.

Comment: @vxxxi did you try to rename it to id in your migration files?

Comment: Thanks guys. That did it. Somehow the column names were changed in the migration files (even including ```initial``` migration file). Reverting the that change fixed the issue.